# LISP - Closest function without setq/setf etc

Tags: lisp, cluster-computing, closest, centroid

I'm trying to write the "closest" function,in Lisp, without using setq/setf etc...

The function finds the nearest vector of a given vector (finding it on a list of lists).

I tried but without sets is too hard,thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the updating of variable is done by recursion:

```lisp
(defun main-function (arg)
  (main-function-helper arg 0 1))

(defun main-function-helper (arg var1 var2)
  (if (= arg var1)
      var2
      (main-function-helper arg (1+ var1) (1+ var2))))
```

When you're done you can put the helper into the main function:

```lisp
(defun main-function (arg)
  (labels ((helper (var1 var2) ; arg left out since it's not changed
            (if (= arg var1)
                var2
                (helper (1+ var1) (1+ var2)))))                 
    (helper 0 1)))
```

This is of course a silly implementation of `1+` for positive arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if I want to do the same thing with float numbers and negatives too? My purpose is to have a function with 2 parameters (the first: a list of lists, the second an element of that list) and to find the closest list (to the second argument) calculating the euclidean distance between him and all the elements of the first argument.

Comment: It doesn't matter what type the arguments are. It will work as long as your function applies functions that work with the type it actually is. Since you know the first is a list of list of numbers and the second perhaps a list of numbers you are all good. float you get by using at least one float in your calculations. Without it you might get a rational. eg. `(/ 3 4) ; ==> 3/4` while `(/ 3.0 4) ; ==> 0.75`. A seasoned lisper might solve your problem with [`mapcar`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mapc_.htm) and/or [`reduce`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_reduce.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Without set, returns a list of lists in case there are ties:

(NOTE: loop macro uses set at some point :P)

```
(defun euclid (v1 v2)
  (sqrt (loop for x in v1 for y in v2 sum 
    (expt (- x y) 2))))


(defun closest (target listoflists distancefn)
  (loop for l in listoflists for d = (apply distancefn (list target l))
    minimizing d into min
    collecting (list l d) into col
    finally (return 
      (loop for (vec dis) in col when 
        (eql dis min) collect vec))))

(closest '(1 2 3) '((1 2 2) ( 1 2 2) ( 2 2 2)) #'euclid)
> ((1 2 2) (1 2 2))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have a little question about the function: if I want to extract only the closest vector (and not target because obviously euclid is 0), how I must change the conditions? Thanks again!

Comment: The function as it is returns a list of the closest vectors (not the target), in case there are more than one at the same closest distance. If there is only one closest vector, it will return a list of one element. 
Hope its clear.
Btw one with sets could be more clear:

`(defun closest2 (target listoflists distancefn)
  (let (closest  (min 9999999))
    (loop for l in listoflists do
      (let ((d (apply distancefn (list target l))))
        (if (< d min)
          (progn
            (setf min d)
            (setf closest l)))))
    closest))`